# How are the scores calculated in Winter Bash's "Hat-Dash"?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I recently noticed that in Winter Bash the scores are not proportional to time played and sometimes I scored more in less time.
[image]
In this image you can clearly see the difference in scores and time taken. So how exactly are the scores calculated in Winter Bash Hat-Dash?

Also, does something like this also happen in other games like Chrome's "Dino Runner"?

Comment: Probably in the game eventloop: `score = score + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));` ...

Comment: Oh thanks, but is there no better way to do this? I mean instead of increasing the score by some random number, maybe increase it by some constant or based on the obstacles in the game? Anyways thanks again :)

Comment: I didn't look at the code .. Maybe each object that flies by you has a different "score" and the objects do appear random and in different time intervals.

Comment: Where to find hat dash?

Comment: @Reza2020 https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Reza2020 you have to earn the right to play hat-dash by wearing the social distancing hat on any site I guess.